# Bash - How to find files that are not modified within a given time period?

Tags: bash, find

I must find and list the first 10 files in a number of directories that have not been modified in the last 10 minutes.

My initial answer was: find . -mindepth 0 -type f -not -mtime 10 -ls | head

But that was marked as wrong likely due to the use of "-not". I need to know why, and what the correct answer is. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps it was wrong because `-mtime`'s argument is days, not minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach (probably requires GNU coreutils)

```
touch -d "10 minutes ago" refFile
find . -type f -not -newer refFile
```

Comment: Yeah, you make a great point in your comment above. I've opted to use -mmin instead and I *think* it should work.

find . -mindepth 0 -type f -not -mmin -10 -ls | head

Comment: Man, I read the man page, was staring at -mtime, did not even register -mmin. Good one.